# Enabling Middleware in Lumen (Laravel)

Tags: php, session, laravel, middleware, lumen

I've been trying out [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) (a micro PHP Framework based on [Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/)) for a few hours and I'm not able to add Middlewares to my project which basically means that I'm not able to use Features like Sessions or CSRF Protection.

My **.env** looks like this:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=some32charslongkey

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=somedbname
DB_USERNAME=someusername
DB_PASSWORD=somepw

QUEUE_DRIVER=database
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
```

and my **bootstrap/app.php** like this:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();

$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler',
    'App\Exceptions\Handler'
);

$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel',
    'App\Console\Kernel'
);

$app->middleware([
    // 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    // 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    // 'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    // 'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    // 'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
]);

require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
return $app;
```

As soon as I uncomment the lines within $app->middleware([ ... ]); the app doesn't show anything on any of the routes.
I'm new to configuration with .env and maybe I just forgot to add something but I can't seem to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `the app doesn't show anything on any of the routes`? Do you get an error? Also check the error logs in `storage/logs`

Comment: It just shows an empty page and there are no errors in the lumen.log :/

Comment: Then please check the server logs as well

Comment: [29-Apr-2015 15:06:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in ~/Sites/lumen-test/vendor/illuminate/cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 52

Comment: If you don't use memcached you should change the .env config to file (or sth else)

Comment: Thank you, it works now.. the advantage of memcached is that it is much faster isn't it?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3148076/1903366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you've enabled the session middleware Lumen is now trying to use memcached as its what you have currently set in your .env file if you change that over do something like file it should work then.

Comment: Thank you, what are the advantages of memcached towards using file? Performance?